# Improving readability of coroutine errors

Tags: android, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

I have retrofit request which returns suspend function:

```
suspend fun getItems(): retrofit2.Response<List<Item>>
```

and I handle it this way:

```
try {
    val response = service.getItems()
    when {
        response.isSuccessful -> handleResponse()
        else -> handleError(Throwable(
        response.errorBody()?.charStream()?.readText()
    ))
    }
} catch (e: Exception) {
    handleError(e)
}
```

The problem is: sometimes I get error in my logs which is not readable enough to catch the problem, for example:

```
viewModel.getItems.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:222)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(Unknown Source:9)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Unknown Source:12)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(Unknown Source:10)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.access$runSafely(Unknown Source:0)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(Unknown Source:22)
```

How can I improve coroutines error handling to improve its readability?

Comment: Not sure if this will fix the issue, but you should re-throw `CancellationException`, otherwise you break cancellation.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wrap the result into `retrofit2.Response` but just expect `List<Item>` then when you invoke `service.getItems()` it will return the list if the call was successful or it will throw an exception as `retrofit2.HttpException`. You can pass that exception to the `handleError` function.

Comment: I need `retrofit2.Response` to read  response codes.

Comment: Hmm, do you care for successful status codes or just for the error ones 400+?

HttpException will provide non-2xx status codes.

Comment: I handle some of 200+ differently

Comment: I'm not aware of any other way to extract status codes and keep the "actual" exception.
From what  I found this is an exception that wraps the "actual" exception. Just a wild guess that you can build the exception from `errorBody.byteStream` which is `InputStream`  -> check this one for how to do it https://stackoverflow.com/a/36084668/9072335 When you have the exception you can check it's `cause` for more descriptive stacktrace.